# how do I ssh Linux VM over virtualbox from windows

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I spin up a Centos7 virtual machine over Virtualbox and trying to access via ssh from putty over windows from another machine in a same network, below are the details of my VM:

IP addresses:

Windows machine details:
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC):
IPv4 Address:  172.30.64.1
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
IPv4 Address : 10.84.5.42

VM details: 192.168.122.1

[Network setting] :Bridge Network

I dont have much knowledge about networking, can someone please help me with this.

I am able to ping from host OS to VM but not from any other machine.

Thanks, Piyush

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are bridged on the network, if it would report the same subnet as one of your connections. It looks like your VM is in NAT mode or is set to local host only.

Since you can ping from the local host then this connection is a Local host only or  in NAT. You need to make sure that the IP Address on the Centos reports the same subnet of either the wired or wireless adapter.

Are you actually using both connections?
Try disabling one and reboot both and try again. I am not use to VirtualBox as I use VMware products but sometimes multi adapters can confuse the VT if it is not set up to use only one connection.